# Collect data from a strongly-typed view in asp.net mvc 3 form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know this may look as an easy to find the answer question but I found many articles about how to send data from controller and show it in the view and no clear way of how to collect/use the submitted data back in the controller.

This is my setup :

I use the default structure that the visual studio creates for mvc project so in the `HomeController` I changed the Ìndex to :

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Create table";
                var model = new List<Auction>();
                model.Add(new Auction
                {
                    Title = "First Title",
                    Description = "First Description"
                });
                model.Add(new Auction
                {
                    Title = "Second Title",
                    Description = "Second Description"
                });
                model.Add(new Auction
                {
                    Title = "Third Title",
                    Description = "Third Description"
                });
                model.Add(new Auction
                {
                    Title = "Fourht Title",
                    Description = "Fourth Description"
                });

                return View(model);
            }

I just hard coded some data so I can play around with it.

then this is my Index view :

@model List<Ebuy.Website.Models.Auction>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table border="1" >
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

And I thought again in my `HomeController` that this would be enough to get the info from the view :

[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult Index(Auction model)
{
    var test = model;
    return View(model);
}
```

Well, it seems it's not that easy. I get this error :

`[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Ebuy.Website.Models.Auction', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Ebuy.Website.Models.Auction]'.]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Type in your view from `List<Auction>` to `Auction` . Because you are passing just the `Auction` and your View has the model type as `List<Auction>` it throws this error. My strong guess is that when you tested it with the List of values you had the Model type in the view as generic List but you chenged your Action later to return Auction but did not change your View.

Change your Model in the view from

```
@model List<Ebuy.Website.Models.Auction>
```

to

```
@model Ebuy.Website.Models.Auction
```

Comment: I did not do anything intentionally. I mean - I want my View to accept List of Auctions because as you can see in my logic I iterate through this List to fill my table. So I need this to be List. So I need to leave the @model to List, any suggestion how to send it back this way?

Comment: So you want your view to take List<Auction> as well as Auction right? What are you doing in the Second HTTPPost Index?

Comment: After your answer in the controller I changed my Index method to: `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<Auction> model)
        {
            var test = model;
            return View(model);
        }`

Comment: By the way changing the controller like this doesn't create error but also clicking the Submit button doesn't get in my [HttpPost] Index method.

Comment: Thats because your submit button is not sending back the List<Auction> so it doesn't find the matching Action... You can try this instead...``public ActionResult Index(Auction model)
{
    var test = new List<Auction>; test.Add(model); 
    return View(test);
}

Comment: In fact it was my mistake. This - `public ActionResult Index(List<Auction> model)` works for my [HttpPost] Index. However I get the description values but lose the ``Title` values on submit. If you can help me with that will appreciate it.